# Percentage match between two strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want something similar to this, two strings then the percentage match between the two, example below

```
string1 string2 percentage match
cali    cali    100%
```

Comment: SQL Server has the `difference()` function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  If you are lucky, it will do what you want, but it is not highly generalizable.  Otherwise, explain what YOU mean by "percentage match".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to write [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) function for that. Algorithm calculates number of insert+delete+substitute operations required to turn one string to another. In worst case scenario number of operations will be equal to length of longer string, so you could easily calculate 0%-100% similarity. There are T-SQL implementations available online, e.g. [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/levenshtein-distance-algorithm) (I didn't test it).

Comment: I had a look at this and I'll have to create a function for it.